# Google Maps callback function didUpdateLocations isn't called on updating location

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, delegates

didUpdateLocations is called once when the view appears and then on updating location, it isn't sending callbacks to this method. My Xcode version is 10.1

```
(Above viewDidLoad)
CLLocationManager *locationManager;

(In viewWillAppear)
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate=self;
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I have already inserted keys in Info.plist file, i.e. NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, NSLocationUsageDescription, NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription.

I'm testing the build on Simulator, and updating location from Simulator Location Button.

Already checked similar questions asked and applied changes but the issue remains. Please assist.

Comment: silly question - but have you enabled 'Allow Location Simulation' in the scheme settings?

Comment: Hi @Russell, Allow Location Simulation is already enabled, and also a default location is set. Even though, current location marker isn't showing up.